# if i click anywhere in the form - form submitting after ajax validation, can anyone tell me how to solve this issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-form-validator

Validation is working good and form also submitting if i click submit button, only problem is form submitting if click anywhere in the page, please help me here. thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(":input[type='submit']").on('click', function(){
            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        });               
         $("#locationName").on('change', function desgCheck()
                {     
                    var locationName = $('#locationName').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../designation/locationName.htm",
                        data: {
                            locationName: locationName
                        },
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            if ($.trim(data) !== 'Data  available')
                            {
                                alert("This Location already exist!!");
                                $("#locationName").val("");
                            } else {
                                $("#desgForm").submit();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                           $("#locationName").val("");
                        }
                    });

                });
                $("#locationName").on('keyup', function desgCheck(){
                     var str = $("#locationName").val();
                    var a = str.toUpperCase();
                    $("#locationName").val(a);
                });
jQuery("#desgForm").validationEngine();
     });
```

HTML:

```
 <form class="form-inline" id="desgForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="../locationSubmit.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="locationName" autocomplete="off"  name="locationName"  class="form-control validate[required]">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: please use just $('input[type=submit]');

Comment: Thanks for your help man.